# MongoDB: Custom command defined in .mongorc.js

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I'd like to define a custom Mongo shell command. Given `.mongorc.js` is like below:

```js
var dbuc;

(function () {
    dbuc = (function () {
        return db.getName().toUpperCase();
    })();
})();
```

I'm getting proper upper-cased name for initial database, yet when I switch to other database I'm still getting name of the initial database instead of current one.

```
> db
test
> dbuc
TEST

> use otherbase

> db
otherbase
> dbuc
TEST
```

I see `.mongorc.js` is run before `mongo` runs and that's why `dbuc` variable has assigned value of initial database - test. But I rather wonder how to get a name of current database whatever base I turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to note:

- In mongo shell, `typeof db` is a javascript object and `typeof dbuc` is string.
- I believe, in your code, `dbuc` value is assigned once and does not change when `use` is called.
- `use` is a `shellHelper` function(type `shellHelper.use` in mongo shell). It reassigns variable `db` with newly returned database object.

One of the solutions, for `dbuc` to work, is to add following code to [.mongorc.js](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file)

```js
// The first time mongo shell loads, assign the value of dbuc. 
dbuc = db.getName().toUpperCase();

shellHelper.use = function (dbname) {
    var s = "" + dbname;
    if (s == "") {
        print("bad use parameter");
        return;
    }
    db = db.getMongo().getDB(dbname);

    // After new assignment, extract and assign upper case 
    // of newly assgined db name to dbuc.
    dbuc = db.getName().toUpperCase();

    print("switched to db " + db.getName());
};
```